# Replacing a dataframe values with other from a list

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
col1,col2,
sth1,sth2,
sth2,sth1,
sth3,sth2
```

and a list with one column with the values from df and the second column with equal other names:

```
valuesdf,valuesnew
sth1,vn1
sth2,vn2
sth3,vn3
```

I would like to change the values from the initial dataframe with the equal values from the second dataframe and have as result this:

```
col1,col2,
vn1,vn2,
vn2,vn1,
vn3,vn2
```

How is it possible to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `match` by looping over the columns of the first dataset ('df1') with the 'valuesdf' column of second, and use that index to get the corresponding 'valuesnew' from 'df2'

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) df2$valuesnew[match(x, df2$valuesdf)])
```